# Eclipse: Scala cannot access Java Class members - just after some cleanup

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

Im trying to use Scala and Java in one project. Im working with the Scla IDE for Eclipse. I have two packages in my Scala Project: one for my scala code and one for my java code.

Now lets say I create new JavaClass with one static member.

```
package javastuff;

public class MyJavaClass {
    public static String MESSAGE = "Im Java";
}
```

After that Im trying to get access to this variale and somehow I cannot. Funny thing, because scala is able to see the Java class "MyJavaClass" just not able to see ***MESSAGE***.

```
import javastuff.MyJavaClass

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(MyJavaClass.MESSAGE)
    }
}
```

- Value MESSAGE is not a member of object javastuff.MyJavaClass

If I use **Project/Clean...** 1-2x times eclipse is maybe starting realizing that the member MESSAGE is really there and everything is fine. Is this normal? Maybe Im doing something wrong, I know eclipse is really a bad IDE and I should maybe try IntelliJ, but somehow I like eclipse and I would like to use later some of my favorite plugins, thats why I would not change the IDE just because of this problem. Any ideas how to handle this problem better?

Comment: Which Scala IDE version you are using?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Scala IDE 2.1.0 Milestone for Juno (http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/dev/site/)

Comment: I was getting this error for a while until I realised I was missing dependencies of the java class; after I added the required jars, eclipse started to recognise the java methods.

Answer (score 1):

Scala doesn't have any static fields. Here is a [blogpost](http://www.eishay.com/2009/05/scala-java-interoperability-statics.html) about it

btw. public static without final is pretty bad design (no encapsulation => possible memory leaks)

Comment: Not sure about your comment, because the same thing is happening with a non static members too.

Comment: use getters and setters to access the private members (don't make them public (static is even worse))

Comment: I have to restart eclipse if I want that eclipse recognize the getter and setter. Is there not an easier way?

Comment: I don't know, I was using some version of Eclipse with embedded Scala and it was pain. You can try some combination of Project -> Clean and Refresh on the project